# Not able to start mysql service in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: server, mysql, raspberrypi, 20.10, database

#### Issue Details:

I was running MySQL v8 on one of my Raspberry Pi 4 (8 GB) for a few months, however the I am unable to start mysql using `sudo service mysql start` since morning and receiving below error message:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

#### Troubleshooting & Analysis

- Re-installed MySQL 8
- Tried to start the MySQL service using the above command, the service started without any issues.
- However, when I updated the data directory from /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file, the issue crept up again.

Does this tell me that there could be an issue on the the data directory ? Any solution to recover from this scenario ?

#### Execution Result: `systemctl status mysql.service`

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-02-02 18:08:10 IST; 1min 16s ago
    Process: 3285 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 3294 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 3294 (code=exited, status=2)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
```

#### error.log

```
2021-02-02T12:38:03.012089Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.10.1) starting as process 3185
2021-02-02T12:38:03.059589Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-02-02T12:38:03.596555Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: fil0fil.cc:10815:initial_fsize == (file->size * phy_page_size) thread 281473363472416
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
12:38:03 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0xaaaadfc38ef0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = ffff9fd7e690 thread_stack 0x46000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x44) [0xaaaaceb08ae4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x294) [0xaaaacdd1e484]
linux-vdso.so.1(__kernel_rt_sigreturn+0) [0xffffacbaf5d8]
/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xd8) [0xffffac24ef58]
/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0xf4) [0xffffac23b50c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ut_dbg_assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, unsigned long)+0x26c) [0xaaaacedb993c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(fil_tablespace_redo_extend(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, page_id_t const&, unsigned long, bool)+0x4a8) [0xaaaaceeedd68]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1e79ba0) [0xaaaacec9aba0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1e7aa44) [0xaaaacec9ba44]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1e7f670) [0xaaaaceca0670]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(recv_recovery_from_checkpoint_start(log_t&, unsigned long)+0x580) [0xaaaaceca1570]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(srv_start(bool)+0x1e68) [0xaaaaced6f7c8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1dc8154) [0xaaaacebe9154]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::bootstrap::DDSE_dict_init(THD*, dict_init_mode_t, unsigned int)+0x6c) [0xaaaace9205fc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::upgrade_57::do_pre_checks_and_initialize_dd(THD*)+0x164) [0xaaaacead8224]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xf9d874) [0xaaaacddbe874]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x21b9d84) [0xaaaacefdad84]
/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7f74) [0xffffac64ff74]
/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xd73dc) [0xffffac2ee3dc]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

#### Execution Result: `sudo service mysql status`

```
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: Tried to put as much info which I could, let me know if I have missed any point.

Comment: Looks like you've run out of storage space. What do you see when you run `df -h`?

Comment: @Matigo this is what I see <br>

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           776M  4.3M  772M   1% /run 
/dev/mmcblk0p2   29G   22G  6.3G  78% /
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       115G  8.4G  107G   8% /database
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M  137M  116M  55% /boot/firmware
tmpfs           776M  100K  776M   1% /run/user/1001

Comment: Only 8% of the available disk space has been utilized by the database

Comment: When your diskspace runs empty mysql is known to get destroyed beyond normal repair.
percona has some backup tools that sometimes work to reconstruct such databases.

Time to consider another database than mysql if that's a problem